# How to set Ext.button.Split not to show arrow when menu is empty?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have Ext.button.Split, for example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text: 'Example',
    handler: function() {
        alert("Click!");
    }
});
```

Right now it does not have any menu items. I want to set the button not to show arrow if there are no items. How ? 
I use EXTJS 4.1 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `split: false` to hide arrow. You can also use `Ext.button.Button` instead of `Ext.button.Split` - when menu is assigned, arrow shows.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AUE6J/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with ExtJS 6.0.1.

Once the splitbutton is rendered (at least into some panels like an action widget in a grid column), simply setting the property:

```
button.arrowVisible = false;
```

...will not work.  You must do this:

```
button.setConfig('arrowVisible', false);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! One quick tip: since it's a config, it has its own setter automagically created for it. `button.setArrowVisible(false)` will do what you want in fewer characters.